# Android Studio - how to make R.string show text in the editor

Tags: android, string, android-studio

Sometimes in the activity or xml, Android studio editor directly shows the text that is mapped for the particular R.string and When I click on that text, it changes to R.string.<>.

Few times, I see activity or xml editor shows R.string.<>, now  from the editor is there a short-cut to see what is the string in that reference without opening strings.xml?

Comment: I don't know how to make the hint show in java code, but you can always do `ctrl+b` while the carret is on the R.string.<> call to go straight to its definition in the `strings.xml` file

Comment: Yes, ctrl+b works. I am seeing if there a solution for hint to be shown.

Comment: you can alos preview the resource by hovering your cursor on it when the resource is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, you can use "Ctrl" + "NumberPad+"/"NumberPad-" to fold/unfold the resource and code chunk.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable it under Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding.

It’s (as far as I can remember) the “Android String References”.

Note, you have to close/re-open the XML for this setting to “show”.
[image: A.S. preferences]

You can see how it looks (some code has been “red taped” for “corporate reasons” but you can see how even the `@dimen/xxx` and the `@string/xxx` in the `contentDescription` has been expanded.

[image: folded strings]

Comment: Keymap > Code > Folding > Expand / Collapse (credit to Jacob's answer)
no need to reopen the editor anymore !

Answer (score 0):

To collapse to the string:  with the cursor on the text, hit +.
To expand to the variable:  with the cursor on the text, hit +.